# return true if only there is exact include

Tags: javascript

Using includes method we get `true` for all of these logs:

```
console.log("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/1.mp3".includes('listen_again_long')); // true
console.log("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/2.mp3".includes('listen_again')); // true
console.log("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/3.mp3".includes('listen')); // true
```

But we know only the first log should return `true` because we have exactly `listen_again_long` inside the longer string.

if we consider this part fixed: `https://example.com/test/media/instructions/`

How we can only return `true` for the first one and `false` for the rest of the logs?

Comment: what's wrong with `.includes('listen_again_long/1.mp3')`? Maybe I didn't understand the question... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you're trying to match only on the first slug in that URL beyond `https://example.com/test/media/instructions/`, and for an exact value in that string, is that right? Your question isn't very clear in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually looking for a certain string enclosed in `/`, so one option would be to simply include both `/` in the argument you are passing to [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
console.log("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/1.mp3".includes('/listen_again_long/'));
console.log("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/2.mp3".includes('/listen_again/'));
console.log("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/3.mp3".includes('/listen/'));
```

You could also do the same thing using [RegExps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```js
console.log(/\/listen_again_long\//.test("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/1.mp3"));
console.log(/\/listen_again\//.test("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/2.mp3"));
console.log(/\/listen\//.test("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/3.mp3"));
```

In both cases you could replace `/listen_again_long/` with the whole thing if you want to make sure the match doesn't happen in a different place:

```
"...".includes("https://example.com/test/media/instructions/listen_again_long/");
```

Or, with RegExp:

```
/https:\/\/example.com\/test\/media\/instructions\/listen_again_long\//.test("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to extract the substring you want to compare against your parameter and then do a straight === comparison.

```
var url = <your passed in mp3 file>;
var s = "https://example.com/test/media/instructions/"
var substring = url.substring(url.indexOf(s) + url.length);
substring = substring.substring(0, url.indexOf("/");

substring === "listen_again_long"
```